# How to resolve the clash between definition of Big O notation and Inductive Hypothesis when proving running time by substitution method?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation, induction

Suppose you have to prove the solution to the following recurrence by Induction,

$$
T(n)=
\begin{cases}
\Theta(1),  & n=1 \\
2 T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+\Theta(n), & n>1
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $\Theta(1)$ and $\Theta(n)$ are notational abuse and they represent arbitrary positive constant and arbitrary linear function respectively.

First, we guess the solution,
$$
T(n)=O(n\log n)
$$
which expanded,
$$
T(n)\le cn\log n \quad \forall n\ge n_0,\text{where }c>0, n_0\in \mathbb N
$$

Now, we want to prove $\forall nP(n)$, where
$$
P(n):T(n)\le cn\log n \quad \forall n\ge n_0,\text{where }c>0, n_0\in \mathbb N
$$

We will assume $P(k)$ for some $k$ and show $P(k+1)$. But what does it mean to assume $P(k)$ for some $k$ here? The expression $\forall k\ge n_0$ hurts by brain since we have taken $k$ to be some natural number and prefixing it with universal quantifier doesn't make sense to me.

How do we go about this?

**Update**

Actually the problem is with $P(n)$. It cannot contain quantifiers. It is atomic in First-order Logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you asking about is [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) theorem, more known as mathematical induction principle. It states, that
$$\begin{cases}{}
P(n_0) \text{ true} & \\
(\forall n \geqslant n_0)\big(P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)\big) & 
\end{cases} \Rightarrow (\forall n\geqslant n_0)P(n) $$

verbally it means, that for proving $(\forall n \geqslant n_0)P(n) $ is enough to prove two sentences: $P(n_0)$ and implication $(\forall n \geqslant n_0)\big(P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)\big) $. In last one $n$ is, so called, [bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables), dummy variable, and can be replaced with any other letter except $P$ and $n_0$. For example it same with $(\forall k \geqslant n_0)\big(P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)\big) $.

**About update**

Sentence under consideration is $T(n)=O(n\log n), n\to \infty\quad (2)$ and it's definition, of course **contain** quantifiers. As $n$ is bound variable in $(2)$, then it is not fully correct to denote it by $P(n)$, because, really, it does not contain $n$. Exact is to write $T\in O(f)$, where $f(x)=x \log x$.

**Example of using**:

Let me show how is it possible to use math. induction with sentences type $f\in O(g)\quad(3)$. Assume $f(n)=g(n)=n$. Formally $(3)$ is following:
$$\exists c>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \forall k > n_0, k\leqslant c\cdot k\quad (4)$$
All variables used are bound except $\mathbb{N}$. Let's choose $c=1=n_0$, denote by $P(k)$ sentence $ k\leqslant  k$ and start proof of sentence $\forall k > 1,P(k)$, using math. induction with respect to $P$. Because holds $P(1)$  and $(\forall k \geqslant 1)\big(P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)\big)$, then proof is finished trivially.

Comment: I understand what mathematical induction is. My confusion is in the following statement. "Assume $P(k)$ is true for some $k\in \mathbb N$". This is same as "Assume that $T(k)\le ck\log k \quad \forall k\ge n_0,$ where $c>0, n_0\in \mathbb N$ is true for some $k\in \mathbb N$". What does "$\forall k\ge n_0$ but for some $k\in \mathbb N$" mean?

Comment: As you pointed out, we want to prove $(\forall k \geqslant n_0)\big(P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)\big) $. For this, we assume $P(k)$ for some $k$ and not $\forall k\ge n_0 P(k)$.

Comment: Statement should be following "Consider any $k \geqslant n_0$. Assume $P(k)$ and prove $P(k+1)$". Word "some" in this context means "any", because you take "some", but without restriction other then $\geqslant n_0$.

Comment: We do consider any $k\ge n_0$. But when we assume $P(k)$, $k$ is a fixed arbitrary natural number. Since after this we want to show $P(k+1)$, it wouldn't make any sense to let $k$ vary in the middle of proof.

Comment: Yes, $k$ is fixed arbitrary with only restriction $k \geqslant n_0$. We are proving implication for such $k$ which means assume $P(k)$ and prove $P(k+1)$.

Comment: but in the statement itself, we are required to work with $\forall k\ge n_0$ which is absurd if $k$ is fixed.

Comment: "fixed" here means, that you take any, arbitrary one with condition $\geqslant n_0$ and work with it.

Comment: Lets say we have picked an arbitrary $k$ for assuming $P(k)$. We have now fixed $k$. So wouldn't $\forall k\ge n_0$ now not make sense?

Comment: We picked arbitrary $k,k \geqslant n_0$

Comment: It seems to me that you're confusing the expression $\forall k \geqslant n_0$ in $(\forall k \geqslant n_0)\big(P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)\big)$ vs in  $P(k):T(k)\le ck\log k \quad \forall k\ge n_0,\text{where }c>0, n_0\in \mathbb N$

Comment: Usually part with quantifiers are first in sentence: so, assume we want to prove $\exists c>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N},  \forall k > n_0, P(k)\quad (1)$. Now this can be proved with several methods. One of them induction. I speak about using induction for whole $(1)$.